# Return not stopping function in Update()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem, where `return;` doesn't stop the Update() function, any idea why?

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Inventory"))
    {
        ToggleInventory(true);
        return;
    }
    if (Input.GetButtonUp("Inventory"))
        ToggleInventory(false);
    //FPS Controller functions
}
```

However, when I hold down `inventory`, the functions below just continue.
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetButtonDown` returns `true` only on the first frame a button begins to be held down. So the next time Update is called (one frame later than the first frame you press the Inventory button), the first `if` condition will be false.

See the docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButtonDown.html

Comment: Thank you! What I will do, is also call the `GetButton` function, because that will always return true (right?). Do you think that that is too ineffective?

Comment: I'm somewhat of a novice at Unity but I'd expect that would work.